# Coffeescript and jQuery not returning the proper this with click event

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I'm trying to write some coffeescript to give me back the link that I clicked and I'm having trouble.

The issue is that the element I'm getting back is the selector that starts this chain but that's not what I'm looking for.

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#js-exercises-links").bind "cocoon:after-insert", (e, inserted_item) ->
    $("#js-exercise-links a.add_fields").data("association-insertion-node", '#js-outline-fields')
    $("select").chosen()

    $(".js-show-set-duration").click (e)=>
      e.preventDefault()
      console.info this
```

In this example, when I look at my console I get back `<div id='js-exercises-links'>` what I really want is the current element I clicked on which would be an instance of `<div class='js-show-set-duration'>`

What am I doing wrong? How do I get $(this) to reference the element clicked on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you want the skinny arrow and not the fat arrow, its hard for me to test this without the html though.

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#js-exercises-links").bind "cocoon:after-insert", (e, inserted_item) ->
    $("#js-exercise-links a.add_fields").data("association-insertion-node", '#js-outline-fields')
    $("select").chosen()

    $(".js-show-set-duration").click (e)->
      e.preventDefault()
      console.info this
```

Comment: Or you could dig it out of `e`.

Comment: When I do that I get the html elements back in the console but not the actual element in the dom. I want the element so I can run more jquery methods on it.

Comment: Dig it out of `e` with `e.target`. What do you the actual element?

Comment: I'm not able to run any jQuery methods on e.target or this with the `->` e.g, $(this).css 'background-color', 'red' doesn't work, nor does $(e.target).css 'background-color', 'red'. It's not modifying that specific element. What I want to do is do $(this).parent but then that returns a jQuery function instead of the neighboring element...

Comment: I figured it out. Chrome decided to update the way that it renders logged objects in the console... had to do object[0] to get the old return syntax back. (So hover highlights the object on the page).